# Minitest i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm using the spec syntax of minitest with describe blocks.
In my `minitest_helper.rb` (what each spec file `require`s) I have:

```
Minitest::Test.i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!
```

This makes the test within a describe block run in order.
Still, the order of describe blocks is random.

How do I make **everything** in-order?

---

**Demonstrating the problem:**

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/documentation'
Minitest::Test.i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!

describe "Block1" do

    3.times.each do |i|
      it "should print #{i+1}"
    end
end
describe "Block2" do

    3.times.each do |i|
      it "should print #{i+1}"
    end
end
```

I expect it to output:

```
Block1
  0001 should print 1
  0002 should print 2
  0003 should print 3
Block2
  0001 should print 1
  0002 should print 2
  0003 should print 3
```

But sometimes `Block2` comes first.Adding more blocks shows that the blocks are generally run in random order.

---

**What do I want this for?**

> Documentation

Randomizing tests is great for making sure tests are independent as they should be (in other words, it's great for debugging the test suite).
After I'm done debugging the test suite, though, I want the test-suite to serve as documentation, and documentation written in random order kind of *sucks*.

Comment: please post some more code or be more specific about the issue.

Comment: I've added a demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Can you just use a seed number for the ordering?

Comment: You want me to wait till minitest gets the order right and then use that seed? With only a few suites, I could be waiting till the universe ends ...

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still looking for a way to do this, put this in your test_helper.rb

```
# disable random test order for any TestCase
ActiveSupport::TestCase.class_eval do
  # http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Test.html#method-c-i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent-21
  i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!
end

MiniTest.remove_possible_singleton_method(:__run)
Minitest.define_singleton_method(:__run) do  |reporter, options|
  suites = Minitest::Runnable.runnables.reject { |s| s.runnable_methods.empty? }
  parallel, serial = suites.partition { |s| s.test_order == :parallel }

  # If we run the parallel tests before the serial tests, the parallel tests
  # could run in parallel with the serial tests. This would be bad because
  # the serial tests won't lock around Reporter#record. Run the serial tests
  # first, so that after they complete, the parallel tests will lock when
  # recording results.
  serial.map { |suite| suite.run reporter, options } +
    parallel.map { |suite| suite.run reporter, options }
end
```

From: https://www.gregnavis.com/articles/how-to-reduce-test-interference-in-minitest.html

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like there was an option to turn this off, so I added it:     https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/pull/550

```
Minitest.should_shuffle_suites = false
```

should now turn it off with the `minitest` from my fork.

Comment: Unfortunately this PR was not accepted upstream.